# Spring Roo 2.0.0.RC1 - Date finder don't work and Object not correct displayed in finder views

Tags: spring-roo

I will build a finder in Roo for a Date Field but when run the application and use the finder i get BindExceptions.

Example

I change clinic example

add field birthday to pet

```
field date --fieldName birthDay --type java.util.Date --notNull --dateTimeFormatPattern "dd.MM.yyyy"
```

add entity projection for pet

```
entity projection --class ~.domain.PetInfo --entity ~.domain.Pet --fields id,name,type,birthDay,owner --entityFormatExpression "#{name} (#{type}) - #{owner.lastName} #{owner.lastName} "
repository jpa --entity ~.domain.Pet --interface ~.repository.PetRepository --defaultReturnType ~.domain.PetInfo
```

remove finder for pet

add formbean and find for pet birthday

```
dto --class ~.domain.PetBirthdayFormBean
field date --fieldName birthDay --type java.util.Date --dateTimeFormatPattern "dd.MM.yyyy"
find add --entity ~.domain.Pet --name findByBirthDay --formBean ~.domain.PetBirthdayFormBean --returnType ~.domain.PetInfo
```

and add the one finder i remove with formbean

```
dto --class ~.domain.PetTypeAndNameLikeFormBean
field string --fieldName name
field enum --fieldName type --type ~.domain.reference.PetType
finder add --entity ~.domain.Pet --name findByTypeAndNameLike --formBean ~.domain.PetTypeAndNameLikeFormBean --returnType ~.domain.PetInfo
```

when i start application i get exception

```
2017-05-11 09:30:45.618  WARN 9476 --- [nio-8092-exec-6] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver :
Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.sp
ringframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'formBean' on field 'birthDay': rejected value [Thu May 11 00:00:00 CEST 2006]
; codes [typeMismatch.formBean.birthDay,typeMismatch.birthDay,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismat
ch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [formBean.
birthDay,birthDay]; arguments []; default message [birthDay]]; default message [Failed to convert pr
operty value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Date] for property 'birthDay'; n
ested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert fro
m type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.util.D
ate] for value 'Thu May 11 00:00:00 CEST 2006'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentExcepti
on: Invalid format: "Thu May 11 00:00:00 CEST 2006"]
```

I use the other finder an see in list birthday not a date is a sequence of numbers. List all pets birthday is shown as date.

**see Images**

[image]

[image]

**Because you think it is not answer but i have found the solution for one Problem and answer it**

**Why can't i answer my own Question????**`

**Now i post the answer in question not clean i think**

Datefield to find don't work i have not solution.

But Problem with Datefields, and Other Objectfield (not String and simple types) in find view i have found problem and solution.
Same Problem like https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO-3907.

**normal Contoller example PetsCollectionThymeleafController Method datatables:**

```
@GetMapping(produces = Datatables.MEDIA_TYPE, name = "datatables", value = "/dt")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<ConvertedDatatablesData<Pet>> datatables(DatatablesColumns datatablesColumns, GlobalSearch search, 
    DatatablesPageable pageable, @RequestParam("draw") Integer draw) {
    Page<Pet> pets = getPetService().findAll(search, pageable);
    long totalPetsCount = pets.getTotalElements();
    if (search != null && StringUtils.isNotBlank(search.getText())) {
        totalPetsCount = getPetService().count();
    }
    ConvertedDatatablesData<Pet> datatablesData = new ConvertedDatatablesData<Pet>(pets, totalPetsCount, draw,            
        getConversionService(), datatablesColumns);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(datatablesData);
}
```

**searchController  example PetsSearchThymeleafController Method byNameAndWeightDt:**

```
@GetMapping(name = "byNameAndWeightDt", value = "/byNameAndWeight/dt", produces = Datatables.MEDIA_TYPE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<DatatablesData<PetInfo>> byNameAndWeightDt(@ModelAttribute("formBean") PetNameAndWeightFormBean 
    formBean, GlobalSearch search, DatatablesPageable pageable, @RequestParam(Datatables.PARAMETER_DRAW) Integer draw) {

    Page<PetInfo> pets = getPetService().findByNameAndWeight(formBean,search,pageable);
    long totalPetsCount = pets.getTotalElements();
    if (search != null && StringUtils.isNotBlank(search.getText())) {
        totalPetsCount = getPetService().countByNameAndWeight(formBean);
    }
    DatatablesData<PetInfo> datatablesData = new DatatablesData<PetInfo>(pets, totalPetsCount, draw);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(datatablesData);
}
```

In Method datatables return Type is responseEntity> and will set with ConvertedDatatablesData datatablesData = new ConvertedDatatablesData(pets, totalPetsCount, draw,
        getConversionService(), datatablesColumns);

The class PetsCollectionThymeleafController has attribut conversionService and getter and setter Method for this. In construktor this field will be set.

```
private ConversionService conversionService;
...
@Autowired
public PetsCollectionThymeleafController(PetService petService, ConversionService conversionService, MessageSource 
    messageSource, ControllerMethodLinkBuilderFactory linkBuilder) {
    setPetService(petService);
    setConversionService(conversionService);
    setMessageSource(messageSource);
    setItemLink(linkBuilder.of(PetsItemThymeleafController.class));
}
...
public ConversionService getConversionService() {
    return conversionService;
}
public void setConversionService(ConversionService conversionService) {
    this.conversionService = conversionService;
}
...
```

The ConversionService convert the elements in table.

But the Methods in SearchControllern don't use ConversionService and so Object like Owner will displayed in List as [object Object] and Dates will be displayed like 1500501600000.

Add ConversionService to SearchContoller and set in Constructor.
Change returntype by..dt Methods and set new parameter DatatablesPageable pageable. In FactoryClass where by..dt will call set new null parameter in call.
Set the return Element

```
  ConvertedDatatablesData<Pet> datatablesData = new ConvertedDatatablesData<Pet>(pets, totalPetsCount, draw,            
        getConversionService(), datatablesColumns);
```

**changes PetsSearchThymeleafController:**

```
...
private ConversionService conversionService;
...
@Autowired
public PetsSearchThymeleafController(PetService petService, ConversionService conversionService, MessageSource 
    messageSource) {
    setPetService(petService);
    setMessageSource(messageSource);
    setConversionService(conversionService);
}
...
public ConversionService getConversionService() {
    return conversionService;
}
public void setConversionService(ConversionService conversionService) {
    this.conversionService = conversionService;
}
...
@GetMapping(name = "byNameAndWeightDt", value = "/byNameAndWeight/dt", produces = Datatables.MEDIA_TYPE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<ConvertedDatatablesData<PetInfo>> byNameAndWeightDt(DatatablesColumns datatablesColumns,
    @ModelAttribute("formBean") PetNameAndWeightFormBean formBean, GlobalSearch search, DatatablesPageable 
    pageable, @RequestParam(Datatables.PARAMETER_DRAW) Integer draw) {

    Page<PetInfo> pets = getPetService().findByNameAndWeight(formBean,search,pageable);
    long totalPetsCount = pets.getTotalElements();
    if (search != null && StringUtils.isNotBlank(search.getText())) {
        totalPetsCount = getPetService().countByNameAndWeight(formBean);
    }
    ConvertedDatatablesData<PetInfo> datatablesData = new ConvertedDatatablesData<PetInfo>(pets, totalPetsCount, draw, 
        getConversionService(), datatablesColumns);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(datatablesData);
}
...
```

**before changes:**
[image: objects not correct displayed]

**after changea:**
[image: Oebjects correct displayed]

Comment: Could you provide the code of the generated finder in the controller .aj file?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem remembers me to the following one:

https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO-3887

We've solved the problem for the RC1 version. However, after analyze your issue, seems like you're having the same problem as the registered one where this issue appear in the finder result table:

https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO-3898

By the moment, there aren't an automatic solution, but you could solve it manually! Edit the `list.html` that contains the table of the result of the finder and include extra `{` to apply format to the date fields.

See:

```
data-th-field="${{birthDay}}"
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Why my answer was deleted????  I describe the solution for one Problem.